# react-draft-wysiwyg flickering once i type into the input field in next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

The input field keeps flickering. Here is where I'm making use of the code (the Editor component). I'm also importing the package with next/dynamic, i do not know if this helps in anyway, Thanks

```
<Editor
      editorState={editorState}
      wrapperStyle={{ backgroundColor: "white", height: "300px" }}
      onEditorStateChange={setEditorState}
    />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest try trim the problem, in what cases its happening and in what cases wont.

1. be sure the css is there. (flickering usually is wrong styling)
2. be sure of being initializing the emptyEditorState with EditorState.createEmpty()
3. is still flickering? force imports statically to check if that matter
4. is still flickering? remove the onChangeHandler leave it empty.
5. bring me feedback :)

This is the official doc example that should work

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { EditorState } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';

const MyEditor = () => {
  const [editor, setEditor] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());
  return (
    <Editor
      editorState={editor}
      wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
      editorClassName="demo-editor"
      onEditorStateChange={setEditor}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this works for me

```
  const Editor = useMemo(() => {
    return dynamic(
      () => import("react-draft-wysiwyg").then((mod) => mod.Editor),
      { ssr: false }
    );}, []);
```

Comment: Perfect mate, especially for Next.js where dynamic imports are required.

Answer (score 1):

Found a fix, don't know if its appropriate though
I wrapped the dynamic import with a useMemo Hook

```
const Editor = useMemo(() => {
return dynamic(
  () => import("react-draft-wysiwyg").then((mod) => mod.Editor),
  { ssr: false }
);}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

could you check don't import it dynamically, is still flickering?

`import { Editor } from "react-draft-wysiwyg";`

`import "react-draft-wysiwyg/dist/react-draft-wysiwyg.css";`

Comment: be sure the css styles are being applied

Comment: since its next js, I have to import dynamically since i want to load on the browser and not on server. I'm also loading the css file correctly

Comment: could you share more code? How editor state is being initiliazed? and how are you storing the state?

Comment: I just found a fix i wrapped the dynamic import of the Editor in a useMemo, I'm guessing each time the component re-rendered it recreates the Edit Component, Thanks.

Comment: you have to set SSR false if the library has to be loaded in the browser, dynamically means lazyloading, is not exactly browser rendering.

`dynamic(() => import('../components/hello'), { ssr: false });`

Comment: Yh, I had ssr set to false